# Контекст для статичного метода

Tags: android, android-studio, static, context, методы

Решил вынести часть кода в метод, чтоб использовать из других классов.
И столкнулся с проблемой: "Не знаю как получить контекст для статичного метода". Android Studio все поподчеркивало. Пока не нашел, как исправить. Может кто подскажет?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static void FAB_add_method(Context context){
    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.price_and_name, null);  //Создаю строку "цена+наименование" из XML-шаблона "price_and_name"
    LayoutOfScroll.addView(item);                           //Добавляю созданную строчку "цена+наименование" в LayoutOfScroll
    EditText edPrice = (EditText) item.getChildAt(0);       //Получаю доступ к EditText-у стоимости только-что созданной строки
    EditText edName = (EditText) item.getChildAt(1);        //Получаю доступ к EditText-у стоимости только-что созданной строки
    ImageButton btnClear = (ImageButton) item.getChildAt(2);//Получаю доступ к кнопке удаления каждой только-что созданной строки
    edPrice.addTextChangedListener(ContentFragment.this);   //Вешаю обработчик изменения текста каждому EditText-у стоимости
    edPrice.setOnFocusChangeListener(ContentFragment.this); //Вешаю обработчик фокуса каждому EditText-у цены
    edName.setOnFocusChangeListener(ContentFragment.this);  //Вешаю обработчик фокуса каждому EditText-у наименования
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(clearProduct);              //Вешаю обработчик удаления при нажатии на кнопку очистки в каждой строке
}
```

Comment: Если метод зависит от контекста объекта, то он не должен быть статическим. Либо передавайте в метод все требуемые параметры.

Comment: "Либо передавайте в метод все требуемые параметры." - можете написать пример? Т.е. как передать контекст в метод?

Comment: Тоже, наверно, пример скриншотом сделаю, чтобы не только я один задолбался код срисовывать с картинки. А вообще - вы ведь знаете, что у методов могут быть параметры? Если знаете, то сможете передавать первым параметром, например, экземпляр данного класса (чтобы у него вызывать метод `getActivity`), а вторым - обработчик клика по кнопке. А перед тем как это делать - хорошенько подумать, действительно оно вам нужно статическим методом в таком виде.

Comment: Извини банально забыл код вставить. А на счет нужно ли мне именно так? Я просто не знаю как другим способом обратиться к методу 1-класса из 2-класса. Для меня известен только такой способ - его и делаю.

Comment: Зачем этот метод должен быть статическим? Это решение ущербное и не приемлемое в нормальной разработке. Если вы чего то там не знаете - повод учится, а не лепить, "как умею". Если ваша проблема в том, как вызвать метод одного класса из другого - задавайте вопрос по проблеме, а не о ваших неверных представлениях о их решении.

Comment: Если нестатическим сделать метод вы не можете, тогда вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/7046508)

Answer (score 1):

1. Если вам внутри метода необходим какой либо объект (а контекст - это объект), то передавайте его туда параметром, как, собственно у вас сделано в приведенном куске кода (а на скриншоте нет).

   ```
   public static void FAB_add_method(Context context){...}
   ```
2. `ContentFragment.this` - это некорректная конструкция для статического метода, так как для него не существует никакого `this`. `this` - это **объект**, а статический метод является **методом класса**. Если вам нужен `ContentFragment.this`, то передавайте его параметром

   ```
   public static void FAB_add_method(Context context, ContentFragment fragment){
       .....
       edPrice.addTextChangedListener(fragment);
       .....
   }
   ```
3. Цель то какая у вас? Что в итоге хотите получить? `обратиться к методу 1-класса из 2-класса` - это не цель, это попытка ее достичь, скорее всего неправильная, из разряда "как закрутить шуруп молотком"